# The sample mean convergence in quadratic mean and in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

$X_1, X_2, \dots $ is a sequence of random variables such that $$\sup_{n \geq 1} E|X_n |^2 < \infty ~~ \text{and}~~  E[X_n X_m ] = 0 ~\text{for}~ n \neq m.$$

I want to show that the empirical *"or sample"* mean of $X_1 , . . . , X_n$ converges to $0$ in quadratic mean and in probability.

My attempt:

Assuming that $E(X_i) = \mu$ and $var(X_i) = \sigma^2$, the sample mean converges in quadratic mean if $E[(\bar{X} \ - \ \mu)^2] = 0$ as $n \rightarrow 0$.

\begin{eqnarray}
E[(\bar{X} \ - \ \mu)^2] = E[\bar{X}^2] - 2 \mu^2 + \mu
\end{eqnarray}
but how to continue to show that it is equal $0$. Also, I don't know how to use the weak law of large numbers to here to prove the convergence in probability?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asked to show is $E(\overline {X})^{2} \to 0$, not $E(\overline {X}-\mu)^{2} \to 0$. This quite easy. Just expand the square and use the hypothesis to get $E(\overline {X})^{2}=\frac 1 {n^{2}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} EX_k^{2}$. If $EX_k^{2} \leq M$ then we get $E(\overline {X})^{2} \leq \frac M n \to 0$.

Any sequence which converges in quadratic mean also converges in probability.

Comment: but why $E(\overline {X})^{2} \to 0$, not $E(\overline {X}-\mu)^{2} \to 0$ ? By the definition of the convergence of sample mean we should verify from  t $E(\overline {X}-\mu)^{2} \to 0$ ?

Comment: or you mean t $E(\overline {X})^{2} \to 0$ because the question asks to show the convergence to $0$ not toward $\mu$

Comment: @Lucas You are asked to show that $\overline {X}$ tends to $0$ in quadratic mean and you are trying to prove that it converges to $\mu$ in quadratic mean.

Comment: thanks I understand. I think you need to modify $E(\overline {X})^{2} \leq \frac M n \to 0$ by dividing over $n^2$

Comment: @Lucas The terms $EX_iX_j$ with $i \neq j$ are $0$. There are $n$ terms of the type $EX_i^{2}$, each of them less than or equal to $M$. So the bound you get is $\frac 1 {n^{2}} (nM)$.